# Argument names for autocompletion in Kile

Tags: macros, kile, auto-completion

Let say I created the following command in my latex document

```
\newcommand{\red}[1]{
  \textcolor{red}{#1}
}
```

When working with the LaTeX editor Kile, the autocompletion gives me something like

```
\red{x} %[Proposed by Kile (autocompletion)]
```

But instead of 'x', I would like Kile propose to me something like

```
\red{text} %[Proposed by Kile (autocompletion)]
```

That could be useful when I have to deal with commands requiring a bunch of arguments. For instance, if I created a command using `\newcommand` requiring 8 arguments, the autocompletion of kile will propose to me something like :

```
\mycommand{x}{x}{x}{x}{x}{x}{x}{x} %[Proposed by Kile (autocompletion)]
```

...but after some times, you do not know who is who! So it would be nice to define 'argument names' so that the autocompletion propose to me something like :

```
\mycommand{date}{name}{stuff1}{stuff2}{age}{address}{city}{whateveritis} %[Proposed by Kile (autocompletion)]
```

To summarize, I would like to change this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIJss.png]

to this :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eXMg.png]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what this has to do with auto-completion. As defined by you, the command `\red` takes a single argument -- be it a single letter ("x") or a longer string ("text") --  while the command `\mycommand` would appear to take eight separate arguments. TeX's syntax rules determine what constitutes a separate argument.

Comment: Thank you Mico for your comments.I may have not well explained what I'm really looking for. I enhance my question accordingly. Let me know if it makes more sense.

Comment: I think that your question is not clear and I can't figure out what the problem is

Comment: I put the word "kile" in the title as I think it's necessary to make that clear right from the start.

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved by [creating a custom auto completion file](http://kile.sourceforge.net/Documentation/html/complete_own_files.html). Such a file has the extension `cwl` and (on my systom) has to be saved under `~/.kde4/share/apps/kile/completion/tex`. The `#` is a comment char in such a file. In such a file you write the commands with the text you want to appear in the arguments.

```
# custom auto-completion file
#

\mycommand{date}{name}{stuff1}{stuff2}{age}{address}{city}{whateveritis}
```

After a restart of kile it can be activated through `Settings -> Configure Kile -> Kile/Complete -> Add` (or similar, it's German on my system).

[image: img: adding the file]

After that it works like a standard auto completion:

[image: img: the auto completion]

Comment: Thank you! The Path is Settings -> Configure Kile -> Kile/Complete -> Add..  and it works fine

Comment: @Palimpseste Glad it works! If my answer helped you [you might want to consider upvoting/accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).