# Custom citing command. Bibtex key as parameter to \newcommand

Tags: macros, citing

I'm new to LaTeX and I want to define an auxiliary command for citing.
What I would like to achieve is a `\newcommand` or similar that takes a BibTeX parameter such as `paper` and produces the same output as:

```
(Image from \cite{paper})
```

Instead I would like to write:

```
\imfrom{paper}
```

I have tried the following:

```
\newcommand{\imfrom}[1]{(Image from \cite{#1})}
```

It works, but it is not type safe, so Kile's auto-completion does not work.
Is there any way this could be done easily?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is Kile able to auto complete personal commands?

Comment: I don't know for certain. I found this:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80093/argument-names-for-autocompletion-in-kile
Although it is something different.

Comment: Yes, see this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/80110/14757

Comment: But this is just for the parameter names, or am I wrong?
How to 'tell it' to show me the full list of citation keys?

Comment: I don't know if Kile does this but I'm sure that TeXstudio does.

Answer (score 1):

Save the original `cite` command and redefine it to do what you want.

```
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{(Image from \oldcite{#1})}
```

If you want to use the old `cite` command just call `\oldcite{}`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{(Image from \oldcite{#1})}
\begin{document}

Using the new command: \verb|\cite{foo}| produces \cite{foo}

Using the old command: \verb|\oldcite[Sec.~1]{foo}| produces \oldcite[Sec.~1]{foo}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{foo} Foo
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note:** now the `cite` command does not accept optional argument.

Comment: Thanks, but now I can't use auto-completion for \oldcite.

Comment: So in this case I'm almost sure that Kile could auto complete user's commands.